# How to display navigation bar in a specific page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, navigator

I have a bottom navigation bar with specified screens for each item. But there's another screen where I want to display my navigation bar which is not assigned to any of the items. And I don't want the navigation bar to all screens, just for that screen. Between the screen with the navigation bar and the specific screen, there're some other screens as well. Does anyone know a way to get this done, really appreciate the help

Navigation bar screen -

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  int _bottomNavIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (index != 1) {
      setState(() {
        _bottomNavIndex = index;
      });
    } else {
      chooseOneOptionBottomSheet(context);
    }
  }

  Widget? pageCaller(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        {
          return const Home();
        }
      case 3:
        {
          return const Notifications();
        }
      case 4:
        {
          return const MyProfile();
        }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool keyboardIsOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: pageCaller(_bottomNavIndex),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: !keyboardIsOpen,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 70.0,
          width: 70.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await availableCameras().then((value) => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CameraPage(
                        cameras: value,
                      ),
                    )));
              },
              tooltip: 'Scan',
              child: const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/scan.png'),
              ),
              elevation: 4.0,
              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        currentIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
              child: const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/home.png'),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
              child: const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/upload.png'),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Upload',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13),
              child: const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/scan.png'),
                size: 10,
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Scan',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
              child: const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/notification.png'),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Notification',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
              child: const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/profile.png'),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        fixedColor: primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: secondaryText,
        selectedLabelStyle:
            const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'InterMedium', fontSize: 12),
        unselectedLabelStyle:
            const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'InterMedium', fontSize: 12),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you may have to add that specific navigation bar to the actual screen. then it will only show up when that specific screen is selected

Comment: if I couldn't find any other solution I guess I might have to go with that